# Publishing two gRPC services with two different certificates on the same port

Tags: c#, grpc

I need to publish different gRPC services with different certificates on the same port.

for example:

1. MyPairingService - should be published on https://myhost:9080/PairingService using cer1
2. MyManagementService- should be published on https://myhost:9080/ManagementService using cert2

It is possible?
how can I achieve it? (without using a reverse proxy)

Comment: You should be able to specify multiple `KeyCertificatePair` instances in SslServerCredentials constructor: `https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/37170cd49579b0f0daf44d19ebae71e3de998aa0/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/ServerCredentials.cs#L140. Once you've setup a server that accepts multiple certificates, you can use ServerCallContext.AuthContext (optionally from within a server-side interceptor) to make each service only accept calls done through connection that has been established through one of the certificates.